# How to setup Active Directory for JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0)

Tags: jboss, active-directory

We migrate from WAS to JBoss EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0) and I'm unable to setup Active Directory to protect our web application. My configuration was inspired by http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=378 but it is not working for 7.5.0.

Here is the snippet of Security Domain in **standalone.xml**

```
<security-domain name="ad_security_domain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://10.175.35.60:389"/>

                            <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=AD Reader,OU=Users,OU=XXX Group,DC=ferradev,DC=fe"/>
                            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="secret"/>

                            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=Users,OU=XXX Company,OU=XXX Group,DC=ferradev,DC=fe"/>
                            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>

                            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=Groups,OU=XXX Company,OU=XXX Group,DC=ferradev,DC=fe"/>
                            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>

                            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
                            <module-option name="Context.REFERRAL" value="follow"/>
                            <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/fop-roles.properties"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

I have this code in my **jboss-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>ad_security_domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

In the config directory (where the standalone.xml is) I have property file **fop-roles.properties**

```
APP_GG_FOP_DEV_ADMINS=Administrators
```

Here is snippet of my **web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Admin Resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/configuration/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Administrators</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

....

<security-role>
        <description>Administrators Role</description>
        <role-name>Administrators</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Bellow are the screenshots of structure of our Active Directory:

**Groups:**
[image]

**Users:**
[image: Users structure]

After successful deploymnet of the web application to JBoss the login page is shown but after filling the credentials I always got the error:

**TRACE [org.jboss.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 100) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null**

Answer (score 4):

I recently spent quite some time configuring LDAP with Active directory. I found a good way to test is to install Apache Directory Server and use that for local debugging.

```
<security-domain name="LdapSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://your.ldap.host:389/"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
        <module-option name="bindDN" value="uid=BindUser,OU=Users,DC=yourCompany,DC=biz"/>
        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="theBindUserPassword"/>
        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="OU=Users,DC=yourCompany,DC=biz"/>
        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="OU=RoleGroups,DC=yourCompany,DC=biz"/>
        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
        <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="0"/>
        <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
        <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="unauthenticated"/>
        <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
    </login-module>
</authentication>
```

Comment: If you look at the screenshots of my AD what module-option should I change to comply with my AD?

Comment: I see you have the following option set <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/> so do the user's login with fop.account.adim as their username?  my advice is to use a LDAP browser like Apache Directory to browse your Active Directory LDAP so you get your filters and context DNs correct.

Comment: Yes, the username is fop.account.admin e.g.

Answer (score 2):

The `RoleMappingLoginModule` doesn't work correctly in JBoss AS7+ (EAP 6+). It can cause the problems in your scenario.

Use either (Option 1) [password stacking](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html-single/Security_Guide/index.html#Password_Stacking) and `UsersRoles` login module or (Option 2) use the role mapping feature directly.

**Option 1:**

```xml
<security-domain name="ad_security_domain" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
      <!-- Put your original module options for LDAP here and add following: -->
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
    </login-module>
    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="optional">
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
      <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/fop-roles.properties" />
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

**Option 2:**

```xml
<security-domain name="ad_security_domain" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
      <!-- Put your original module options for LDAP here -->
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
  <mapping>
    <mapping-module code="PropertiesRoles" type="role">
      <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/fop-roles.properties" />
    </mapping-module>
  </mapping>
</security-domain>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I tried both options but still the same error. So it seems the problem is also in module options for LDAP. Would you be so kind to inspect it and help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

The role constraint in your web.xml says Administrators but the different roles that are possible from your roleCtxDn OU=Groups,OU=XXX Company,OU=XXX Group,DC=ferradev,DC=fe are APP_GG_FOR_DEV_ADMINS, APP_GG_FOR_DEV_MANAGERS, APP_GG_FOR_DEV_USERS and APP_GG_FOR_DEV_WS_ADMINS.

Also use all the TRACE logging options described in https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SecurityFAQ to help work out your problem.

Comment: user "kwart" gave 2 options how to remap the roles